# ZMQ Subscribe and Publish Simultaneously

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm learning ZMQ in Python. I'm trying to have the Publisher to send a message and receive message stating that the message was received from the Subscriber. The issue I'm having is that the Publisher gets stuck at the Print statement "Data sent" and the Subscriber doesn't get the data, it gets stuck at the Print statement "Getting Message...". Any help would be appreciated.

**Publisher**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import zmq
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Publish connections
outPort = int(os.environ.get('OUTPORT', "8760"))  # GMH 0MQ bus
contextPub = zmq.Context()
socketPub = contextPub.socket(zmq.XPUB)
socketPub.bind("tcp://*:%s" % outPort)
outTopic = "xmltest"

# Subscription connections
dataSource = os.environ.get('DATASOURCE', 'tcp://localhost:8761')
contextSub = zmq.Context()
socketSub = contextSub.socket(zmq.SUB)
socketSub.connect(dataSource)
topicfilter = "c2test"
socketSub.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

# Create and test writing xml
data = et.Element('myMessage')

element1 = et.SubElement(data, 'simpleType')

sElem1 = et.SubElement(element1, 'Freq_Center_MHz')

sElem2 = et.SubElement(element1, 'Bandwidth_MHz')

sElem3 = et.SubElement(element1, 'samplerate_msps')

sElem4 = et.SubElement(element1, 'time')

sElem1.text = '100'
sElem2.text = '56.1'
sElem3.text = '56.1'

while True:
    myDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")
    sElem4.text = str(myDateTime)
    bXml = et.tostring(data)
    socketPub.send_string("%s %s" % (outTopic, bXml))
    print("Data Sent")
    time.sleep(1)

    messageStr = socketSub.recv(flags=0)
    print("Hello")
    print(messageStr)

socketPub.close()
```

**Subscriber**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import zmq
import os

# Publish connections
outPort = int(os.environ.get('OUTPORT', "8761"))  # GMH 0MQ bus
contextPub = zmq.Context()
socketPub = contextPub.socket(zmq.XPUB)
socketPub.bind("tcp://*:%s" % outPort)
outTopic = "c2test"

# Subscription connections
dataSource = os.environ.get('DATASOURCE', 'tcp://localhost:8760')
contextSub = zmq.Context()
socketSub = contextSub.socket(zmq.SUB)
socketSub.connect(dataSource)
topicfilter = "xmltest"
socketSub.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

while True:
    print("Getting Message...")
    messageStr = socketSub.recv()
    print("Message Received")
    res = messageStr.decode().split(" ")[1].split("'")[1]

    tree = et.fromstring(res)
    for child in tree.findall("./simpleType/*"):
        print("%s: %s" % (child.tag, child.text))

    print()
    print("Sending Acknowledgement.")
    print()
    receive = "Message Received"
    socketPub.send_string("%s %s" % (outTopic, receive))
```

Comment: Does it work when you use the numeric IP address (`127.0.0.1`) instead of the name `localhost`?

Comment: Also, you seem to implement something that is more like a request/response pattern. REQ/REP sockets might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @rveerd, I switched to REQ/REP sockets and it works exactly how I wanted it to.